# Apache virtual host and .htaccess

Tags: security

I`m using apache2 on ubuntu 11. I want to secure my wordpress site with .htaccess rules, but I understand that it is preferable to put the rules in the apache config file (httpd.conf). If I understand correctly, the virtual site config file (under /etc/apache2/sites-available) is the config file for my wordpress, and not the main apache config.

I want to put Mod_rewrite rules on my site, but when I put it in the config file of the virtual host, apache wont start (file to read the rules), so, Do I have to use .htaccess, or can I use the virtual host config file. (this is what I want to accomplish: http://journalxtra.com/websiteadvice/wordpress-security-hardening-htaccess-rules-4025/)

Thank you! asaf

Answer (score 1):

You can use the rewrite rules in the site's virtual conf file under the directory Site's Available. Do something like this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

    RewriteEngine On
    Rule one
    Rule two
    ...

    </VirtualHost>
```

The important bit is to enable the RewriteEngine before the the rewrite rules.

Not sure but I don't think all the rewrite rules will work in that context (I should test them and update the post). Try adding different blocks between server restarts (install Webmin for easy admin of the server) then let me know which blocks are interfering with the server.